# django form isn't inserting values from views.py file

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I'm trying to insert values into a Django Database using both HTML and a generated value from views.py

This is my views.py

```
def NewPassword(request):
    if request.method == "POST":  
        if request.POST.get('app_name') and request.POST.get('url') and request.POST.get('username') and request.POST.get('email')  and request.POST.get('Category'):
            form = PasswordsForm()
            
            form.app_name = request.POST.get('app_name')
            form.url = request.POST.get('url')
            form.username = request.POST.get('username') 
            form.email = request.POST.get('email')  
            form.category = request.POST.get('Category')      

            print(form.app_name,form.url,form.username,form.email,form.category)      
            
            new_password = GeneratePassword()
            new_password = HashPassword(new_password)
            form.password = new_password
        
            if form.is_valid():  
                print("Form saved")
                form.save()  
                return redirect('/')  
        
        else:
            form = PasswordsForm()
            
            form.app_name = request.POST.get('app_name')
            form.url = request.POST.get('url')
            form.username = request.POST.get('username') 
            form.email = request.POST.get('email')  
            form.category = request.POST.get('category')            
            form.password = request.POST.get('password')

            print(form.app_name,form.url,form.username,form.email,form.category,form.password)      

            if form.is_valid():  
                print("Form saved")
                form.save()  
                return redirect('/')  
            
            if form.is_valid() != True:
                print("Invalid Form")

    else:  
        form = PasswordsForm()
    form = PasswordsForm()
    
    return render(request,'manager/create.html',{'form':form})
```

I get the Invalid Form error because the form fails the `if form.is_valid() != True`

I don't think it's a form error because it's fully generated by Django.
It is failing the is_valid condition but all the specific values have been added to the form.

This is the models.py file

```
TECH = 'TECH'
NONE = 'NONE'
BIZ = 'BIZ'
EMAIL = 'EMAIL'
ENT = 'ENT'
FIN = 'FIN'
GAMES = 'GAMES'
NEWS = 'NEWS'
OTHER = 'OTHER'
SHOP = 'SHOP'
SOCIAL = 'SOCIAL'
SPORTS = 'SPORTS'
TECH = 'TECH'
TRAVEL = 'TRAVEL'
UTIL = 'UTIL'

CATEGORIES = (
    (TECH,'Technology'),
    (NONE,'No category'),
    (BIZ,'Business'),
    (EMAIL,'Email'), 
    (ENT,'Entertainment'),
    (FIN,'Finance'),
    (GAMES,'Games'),
    (NEWS,'News'),
    (OTHER,'Other'),
    (SHOP,'Shopping'),
    (SOCIAL,'Social media'),
    (SPORTS,'Sports'),
    (TECH,'Tech'),
    (TRAVEL,'Travel'),
    (UTIL,'Utilities'),
)

class Passwords(models.Model):
    
    app_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    url = models.URLField()

    username = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField(null=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    category = models.CharField(choices=CATEGORIES,default='No Category',max_length=100)
```

Comment: use `forms.error` to display errors in the form when you are checking `form.is_valid()` then in else print `form.error or form.errors`.

Comment: it's not printing it

Comment: debug it or log it to console

Comment: @macintushar You are using in your models.py emailfield and urlfield so make sure it is entered in valid format...

Comment: Any particular reason you are doing this painful `form.field_name = request.POST.get('field_name')`? You do know that you could have simply written `form = PasswordsForm(request.POST)` and the form would have taken **all** the data it needs directly on its own?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat the reason I was doing that is because I wanted to add specific data to the Form that wasn't inputted via HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out the answer, it was registering as an empty form and views.py had

```py
form.category = request.POST.get('Category')
```

when it should've had

```py
form.category = request.POST.get('category')
```